# Use duplicate email id's in user_ table in liferay

Tags: liferay

I am having one numeric screenName 12345 which has it's emailAddress enteremail@12345.com in user_ table of liferay. When i am creating another screenname enteremail@12345.com the emailAddress field has enteremail@12345.com for the same table. So when i am trying to log in with screenname enteremail@12345.com liferay is throwing exception. 
Stack trace:

```
ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:101] Duplicate entry '10112-enteremail@12345.com' for key 'IX_615E9F7A'
 ERROR [OpenSSOAutoLogin:138] com.liferay.portal.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
com.liferay.portal.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:91)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.UserPersistenceImpl.updateImpl(UserPersistenceImpl.java:477)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.UserPersistenceImpl.update(UserPersistenceImpl.java:441)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUser(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy70.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:149)
    at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin.addUser(OpenSSOAutoLogin.java:170)
    at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin.login(OpenSSOAutoLogin.java:126)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.opensso.OpenSSOFilter.processFilter(OpenSSOFilter.java:130)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:193)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.doFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocalcache.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.BatchSessionImpl.update(BatchSessionImpl.java:75)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.BatchSessionUtil.update(BatchSessionUtil.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.UserPersistenceImpl.updateImpl(UserPersistenceImpl.java:472)
    ... 59 more
```

I am using Liferay 5.2.3 version. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique index in USER_ table on EMAILADDRESS+COMPANYID column. It appears that the 2nd user is not being created during OpenSSO login because of preexisting user with same email.
The easiest solution would be to change the 1st user's email (either from Liferay GUI or database) and only then try creating the 2nd user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can i remove that index as i want to have two users with the same emailAddress but different screennames?

Comment: Here are some tips like changing the index to non-unique and checking for DuplicateUserEmailAddressException: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/7554177 You would be losing the ability to authenticate by email by doing this. And there may be other unexpected problems.

Answer (score -1):

Got the Solution. Dropped Index IX_615E9F7A from Liferay and it is working .....